# pass different types of variable with ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am going to post the values of mutiple checkboxes and textboxes to a php page using click button with the aid of ajax call. In html I have:

```
  <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" />
  <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="params[]" id="params" class="params" value="Value1">Value1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="params[]" id="params" class="params" value="Value2">Value2<br>

<input type="button" value="get parameters" id="getparams" name="getparams"/><p>
<div id="response"></div>
```

in jscript I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getparams").click(function(){

           var field1 = $("#field1").val();
           var field2 = $("#field2").val();

           var params = {'params[]' : []};
           $(":checked").each(function() {
             params['params[]'].push($(this).val());
           });

          var datastr = '&field1=' + field1 + '&field2=' + field2 + '&params=' + params;

           $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "page.php",
           data: datastr,
           cache: false,
           success: function(html){
           $("#response").fadeIn("slow");
           $("#response").html(html);
           }
   });
           return false;
   });
});
```

So I push the checkbox values into an array (params) and the textbox values into separate variables (field1 ,field2). In php I can access `field1,field2` but I can't access the array `params`.

```
echo $_POST['field1'];// I can access..
echo $_POST['params']; // I get [object Object] response
```

what is the problem here ?

Comment: Can you please fix the obvious syntax error (missing apostrophe)? Also, are you really targeting only jScript (IE)?

Comment: fixed now my apologies. I am only trying to pass variables from client side to server side (php).. if that is what you meant.

Comment: You will want to have a look at [jQuery's `serialize` method](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). No need to reinvent the wheel :-)

Answer (score 0):

your params array ( considered an object ) needs to be serialized before adding it to the datastr variable.

An easier way would be to use .submit function, which would do all that heavy lifting for you: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve this with `serialize` method however the following method works fine.
If I rewrite html checkboxes with:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="params" class="parameters" value="Value1">Value1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="params" class="parameters" value="Value2">Value2<br>
```

To determine which input elements are checked in jQuery I can use:

```
       var params='';
        $('.parameters:checked').each(function(){
            params=params+','+$(this).val();
        });
```

instead of:

```
       var params = {'params[]' : []};
       $(":checked").each(function() {
         params['params[]'].push($(this).val());
       })
```

In php if I use `$_POST['params']` I get something like `,value1,value2` which can be then trimmed by `substr($_POST['params'],1)` OR if I want to get an array I can use `explode(',',$_POST['params']);`
and then remove the first element which is empty by using
`array_slice($params,1)`